# Python 2 - Print in every loop, all time that my loop works, I want to print it

Tags: python

E.g. this code doesn't work:

```
score = 1
while True:
    if (score < 500):
      hahhahaah
      hahahahha
      score += 50
```

in this looping increases score, like below. The only thing I want is that print this score every single time.
I want to print every time like until the script closes: 51, 101, 151, 201....

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask, but if you use `while True:` your loop will never end unless you have a `break` statement somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, i edited this question, thanks for help anyway

Comment: http://thomas-cokelaer.info/tutorials/python/print.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn basic I/O in Python and how loops work.

If you just want to spit out the score, you need a `print` statement to do that.  I see you also have an "if (score < 500)` in there, you can get rid of it and do that if check in the loop.

With the print statement and the loop altered you get this (corrected since posting for Python 2 syntax):

```
score = 1
while score < 500:
    print score
    score += 50
```

Once score is over 499, the loop will end and the program will just 'exit'.

You should also consider reading up more on the basics of Python, such as through the [Python 2 tutorial/introduction](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming) documentation by the Python developers.  It explains how to do while loops and print statements so you can see the value of a specific variable and such.  (I would advise that you look into Python 3, however, as Python 2 will be dead within two years' time and not supported by upstream anymore, so Python 3 is the new 'standard' Python that you should probably get used to; it's not too different from Python 2, but it's different enough to need some effort to switch some things over to it)

Comment: Thanks for helping, is only this, i commit some mistake in my codes thats why the print doesnt work. Thanks, after see it and read the page of this link i realized my mistake